# Java JComboBox suppress change listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have an ActionListener on my JComboBox, but I want it to triger ONLY when pressing enter, not when changing the item, something like

```
comboBox.trigerActionListenerOnChange(false);
```

hope that something like this exists :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following client property and the ActionListner will only fire when clicked or the Enter key is used to select the item.

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(...);
comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
comboBox.addActionListener(...);
```

Comment: See also `BasicComboBoxUI`.

Comment: And if i dont want it to triger on clicks, but only on enter press? Or is there a way how to find out from the ActionEvent?

Comment: Why do you care? Some users like to use the mouse and some like to use the keyboard. MS and other companies have spend millions of dollars defining user interfaces. Your interfaces would be confusing to everybody but yourself. Users would be writing up bug reports stating that the combobox wasn't working on a mouse click.